# Reportlab table cell reflow - is there a way to style the first and last cells on a page when a table is multiple pages?

Tags: cell, reportlab, reflow

I've got a multi-page table with lots of rows.  I want the topmost row on any page to have more space above and have a line above it.  Likewise, I want the bottommost row on any page to have a space below it and a line below it.  I know how to add the styles to the row.  I just need a way to determine first and last rows.

Answer (score 1):

well in the table styles, the first row is always (0,0),(-1,0) right? start in upper left and go all the way across?

Will you always have the same number of rows, If it is the same you could just manually set it. Say there are 10 rows then you could set the last row using (0,9)(-1,9).

Comment: What if we don't know the number of rows??